# creating a class over faye-websocket in ruby

Tags: ruby, websocket, eventmachine, faye

I am not experienced with event driven programming and I am struggling to get my head around how I would write a class on top of faye-websocket to hide the complexity of what I am doing.  Here is the idea of what I want to do:

```
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'pp'

class Rubix

def initialize(url, options)
@response = {}
EM.run {
  ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new(url, nil, options)

  ws.on :open do |event|
...
  end

  ws.on :error do |event|
    p [:error]
  end

  ws.on :message do |event|
    resp = JSON.parse(event.data)
    rid = resp['id']
    response[rid] = resp
  end

  ws.on :close do |event|
    p [:close, event.code, event.reason]
    ws = nil
  end

}

end

def call_qes(json_rpc, id)
  ws.send(json_rpc)
  while @response[id].nil?
    sleep(1)
  end
  resp = @response.delete(id)
  return resp
end

end
```

Is this a valid approach?  If not how should I put a layer of abstraction around this?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the use of the call_qes method? You're using an instance variable as a sort of global that you can access in and out of threads. For this type of thing you should use something more dependably atomic, like a database.

Comment: Why not use a websocket framework (I'm the author of one, [plezi.io](http://www.plezi.io), so I'm curious)?

Comment: @maxple So basically the websocket server I am accessing is basicaly rest over websokets.  It takes a json request and returns a json response.  All I am trying to  do it be able to do multiple requests/response on the same websocket connection really.

Comment: @myst I'll take a look.  To be honest the reason I ended up with faye-websocket is it was the first thing I found an example for that let me specify client certs for (which is what options is above).

So if plezi supports WSS and client certs its a definite option.

Comment: Oh.. and it needs to run on windows.

Comment: @LeighK , plezi.io requires Linux/BSD and supports `wss` only behind a TLS proxy (such as nginx)... so it might not fit your needs... This is because plezi.io utilizes the [proposed Websocket Rack Specification](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine/blob/master/SPEC-Websocket-Draft.md) which [was discussed at length](https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/1107) but seems to be only supported by iodine, which is a young and fast server written in C for BSD / Linux systems.